# sql procedure check inputs before insertion

Tags: sql

so I have the following code and im just trying to check the inputs before executing the insert statement, I know the charat would be preferential here but if poss I would like to use the substr method, return an error message if it fails. I dont know if i need the out error message or there is a simpler way of doing this. I think its just a syntax error with my if statement. could anyone point me in the right direction? thanks

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_test (IN teacherid varchar, IN name varchar, IN startdate, OUT
errorMsg varchar)
BEGIN
if (SUBSTR(teacherid ,1,1) = 'm')
and(cast(SUBSTR(teacherid ,2,2) as smallint) between 0 and 50)
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test (teacherid , name , startdate) VALUES (teacherid , name , startdate);
END
```

Comment: That check seems to indicate a horrible data model. Don't mix different types of information in a single column. If you break this in several columns just apply a check constraint and forget the trigger.

Comment: yes it is, and I do have constraints but I would like to implement this particular bit of code as above, just not sure whats wrong with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way you have to select error msg....

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_test (IN @teacherid varchar, IN @name varchar, IN @startdate datetime, OUT @errorMsg varchar)
As
BEGIN
if ((SUBSTR(teacherid ,1,1) = 'm')
and(cast(SUBSTR(teacherid ,2,2) as smallint) between 0 and 50))
BEGIN
INSERT INTO test (teacherid , name , startdate) VALUES (teacherid , name , startdate);
END
Else
BEGIN
Set @errorMsg='Error Msg Not inserted record'
Select @errorMsg
END
END
```

Comment: hi thanks for that, any thoughts on the syntax error, its the "begin" on line 6 which is the problem so I presume ive missed something in my if statement? thanks.